# Counting the occurrence of a word in a string in Java

Tags: java

I read a word from the user (query)
I show the number of occurrences of that word in each line of a given textfile

Sample text file:

> cat
>
> cat dog cat
>
> cat

if I search on cat .. the occurences I get are 1, 2, and 3 .. 3 is wrong..

so any help to fix the counter??

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class main {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
    

    System.out.println("Search: ");
    String query = ToRead();
    int counter =0;
    int lineNumber=0;
    int k=0;

    System.out.println("Searching for"+ " " + query);
    
    File file = new File("C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/test.txt");
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file);
    //List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
     
    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        counter=0;
         
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("line " + lineNumber + " :" + line);
        
        int result = line.indexOf(query); 
        while(result !=-1) 
        { 
            result = line.indexOf(line,result+1); 
            counter++; 
        } 
        System.out.println(counter);
                    
        //System.out.println("The string occurred "+counter+" times");           
        
        lineNumber++;           
    }   
}

public static String ToRead()
{
    String s;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    s = in.nextLine();
    return s;
}
```

}

Comment: I understand that you are just learning Java, but still: please take some time and read about java coding guides for java source code. Naming your class "main" is very much wrong. I would even go one step further: while learning how to program, also learn how to write **good** programs; for example by carefully studying https://cleansourcecode.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/clean-code.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to count number of occurrences of string is to use `split`method(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
int numberOfOccurrences = split("find me", -1).length - 1;
```

Comment: What is the result of `"this is the search string".split("cat").length;` ? ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I had a mistake in my answer. You can see edited version of my answer now.

Comment: This time the answer is correct. I still would not recommend this practice though, it feels too much like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

What if you reset the counter right after you print out your answer? So under your print line just set the counter to zero. That will make sure you change or reset it. Hope it helps but I have no way to test it out at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringUtils.countMatches`, like this:

```
count += StringUtils.countMatches(line, query);
```

If you want to print out the numbers in each line, then

```
count = StringUtils.countMatches(line, query);
```

I do not understand your problem exactly. If you want to print out all the occurrences line-by-line, then the second should be used. Otherwise, the first should be used, but with the `println` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, change your inner loop to

```
int result = line.indexOf(query); 
while(result !=-1) 
{ 
     counter++;
     result = line.indexOf(query,result+1); 
} 
System.out.println(counter);
```

Second, can you give the current output of your program and your expected output?

Comment: @Buuman actual output Searching for cat
line 0 :cat
1
line 1 :cat dog cat
1
line 2 :dog
1
expected output Searching for cat  line 0 :cat
1
line 1 :cat dog cat
2
line 2 :dog
0

Comment: Here you are saying your third line (line 2) reads 'dog' whereas in your question you said it reads 'cat'. Could you update your question with these actual and expected output? That will help clarify your problem :-)

Comment: Also, please rerun your program with the loop as in my answer (because you had at least one bug where you search the string variable `line` for the string contained in the variable `line`), then update your answer with the new code and the new output. What does it say now?

Answer (score -1):

You should only increment `counter` if `result` is not -1.

In your `while` loop you are incrementing it once more, even if `result` is -1.

Comment: Where did he increment the counter if the result was -1?

Comment: In here: `result = line.indexOf(line,result+1);     counter++; `